# PHP: Is valid to call a function passing by reference a variable not yet defined?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

As the title asks: is ok to call a function passing by reference a variable not yet defined ?

Let's assume the variable will be set **inside** the function in any case.

I post example code to give context to the question:

```
function doStuff( &$error )
{
    $error = false;

    // Start doing stuff...
    // ...

    if( /* SOMETHING WRONG */ )
    {
        $error = "Something went wrong";
    }

}


doStuff( $err ); // $err is not defined!


if( $err !== false )
{
    // Handle the error, ex.

    echo $err;
    exit;
}
```

I tried on the cli with `error_reporting ( E_ALL );` and no errors were reported.

Still I ask confirmation if it's safe, has no drawbacks, is not bad coding pattern...

Comment: Passing arguments by reference **is** a bad coding pattern/habit. There is no hint for the person that reads the `doStuff($err)` line that the function will modify the variable passed as argument. Also, there is no hint that the function does not accept a literal or a constant as argument.

Comment: @axiac If you're calling random functions without reading their documentation, there's nothing that can help you. Referenced parameters are a perfectly valid technique for certain situations.

Comment: It is very useful when you want to return a boolean and update some array data. However, this can also be accomplished by using an object (oop) that stores any errors and you can add methods for extra functionality. E.g. $errorObj = new ErrorMessage(); doStuff($errorObj);

Comment: If you're interested in the anti-references argument: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-do-not-use-php-references.html

Comment: @JaredFarrish thank you, very interesting and scary. The more I learn about PHP the less I love it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables which are passed as referenced parameters do *not* have to be initialised beforehand; what you're doing is fine. A classic example of such a use case is `preg_match`:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

The `&$matches` parameter is used sort of as a secondary optional output channel in addition to the normal `return` value (an `int`). Since that is one of the primary uses of pass-by-reference values, the language designers have taken care that it can be used in the simplest way possible:

```
if (preg_match($foo, $bar, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Passing the variable as argument for the referenced parameter initialises the variable in the caller's scope. If you *had to* use it this way every time, this would lead to pretty annoying code:

```
$match = null;
if (preg_match($foo, $bar, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Comment: the "annoying code" situation is exactly what I what to avoid, as in the code I posted as example. Thank you for the detailed answer

Answer (score -1):

I would consider that fine, and do it myself often - in right the design you showed. It depend how 'purist' you want to be; there are probably people who say you shouldn't do that. Either way it is important to clear or preset the variable right at the beginning of the function.

The only drawback is that potentially a larger code base is maintained by multiple people or groups, and the person working on the caller might not be in contact with the person working on the function. This can lead to issues if the design is not known to one of them, as he could assume the variable *is* already initialized - and this is why a more puristic approach would say to not do it.